# Keyword 'final' para variáveis java

Tags: java

A keyword final do java para variáveis significa que ela só vai receber um valor uma vez, certo?

Se eu tenho várias variáveis em uma função e eu sei que elas não devem receber nenhum valor posteriormente é bom declarar elas como "final"?

```
void foo() {
final int a = 0;

// executa alguma coisa
final int b = 0;
// ...
final String a = "a";
}
```

Essa declaração como final vai fazer alguma diferença importante no código compilado? Vai ter ganho/perda de desempenho?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não há qualquer relação com desempenho. O principal motivo é apenas para ligar algumas verificações a mais feitas pelo compilador em busca de erros.

Quando você põe o modificador `final` numa variável, está dizendo ao compilador para te dar um erro de compilação se você por algum descuido atribuir duas vezes alguma coisa à variável. No caso de variáveis estáticas ou de instância, o compilador também te avisa com um erro de compilação se você simplesmente esquecer-se de atribuir algo. Isso é especialmente útil quando você mexe num código que desenvolveu há meses ou anos atrás.

Em resumo, é algo para evitar que o programador possa atirar no seu próprio pé em alguns casos.